# C++ old-style cast warning on SIG_ERR

Tags: c++, casting, signals

While compiling some C++ code using `g++ (gcc version 4.2.1 20070719)` (OpenBSD 5.6 to be specific) with the `-Wold-style-cast` flag, I ran across an old-style cast warning for some signal handler code that I'm not sure where the cast is happening.

MCVE:

```
// compile with g++ file.cpp -Wold-style-cast
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

typedef void (*sighndlr)(int);

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    std::cout << "got sig: " << sig << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // warning: use of old-style cast
    sighndlr sh = SIG_ERR;

    // warning: use of old-style cast
    void (*sigerr1)(int) = SIG_ERR;

    // warning: use of old-style cast
    void (*sigerr2)(int) = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(SIG_ERR);

    // warning: use of old-style cast
    void (*sigerr3)(int) = reinterpret_cast<void(*)(int)>(SIG_ERR);

    // warning: use of old-style cast
    if (std::signal(SIGABRT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        std::cout << "error install SIGABRT" << std::endl;
    }

    // no errors or warnings
    if (std::signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler) == sigerr1) {
        std::cout << "error install SIGTERM" << std::endl;
    }
    // no errors or warnings
    std::signal(SIGSEGV, sig_handler);

    // This was just to confirm SIG_ERR wasn't some weird definition
    // error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(int)' to 'void* (*)(int)'
    // void* (*e0)(int) = SIG_ERR;
    return 0;
}
```

The warning isn't causing any issues and I figured for `void (*sigerr2)(int) = static_cast<void(*)(int)>(SIG_ERR)` it's on overly cautious parsing error on the part of the `-Wold-style-cast` flag, but I was more curious why it would give me a warning on `std::signal(SIGABRT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR` and not on `std::signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler) == sigerr1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning isn't because of your code, it's in `<signal.h>` where `SIG_ERR` is defined. I don't have a Linux distribution right now to check, but a quick google found this:

```
#if defined(_ANSI_SOURCE) || defined(__cplusplus)
#define SIG_DFL     (void (*)(int))0
#define SIG_IGN     (void (*)(int))1
#define SIG_ERR     (void (*)(int))-1
#else
#define SIG_DFL     (void (*)())0
#define SIG_IGN     (void (*)())1
#define SIG_ERR     (void (*)())-1
#endif
```

It's obviously implementation defined, but I'm certain that if you grep your `<signal.h>` you'll find something similar.

Comment: As a side note, I'm a firm believer that this warning shouldn't be used. There's nothing wrong with "old" style casts, only with programmers who can't read code.

Comment: That was it! Should've grep'd before I leaped .. I think you and the BSD crew might get along: from `signal.h` in my distro right above the only definitions for `SIG_ERR`, et al. `Language spec says we must list exactly one parameter, even though we actually supply three.  Ugh!`